# Azure VM IP and its geolocation

Tags: ip-address, geolocation

I shutdown my Azure VM everyday in the evening, when it comes online the following morning it gets a new public IP (which is fine for me). However the IP location if I do WHOIS lookup sometime shows that its located (geolocation) in EAST/WEST/CENTRAL etc.

Now this geolocation is causing an issue for me especially with gmail. Gmail detects this as an issue and blocks my access (via Python script using smtplib) and my alerting script fails.

My Azure VM is defined to be in "US EAST", as long as it stays there my gmail script works just fine.

Attached is the [image of the alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0Xe.png) I get from gmail.

Any help on how to get out of this situation is appreciated.

Comment: You can disable the Gmail alerts:  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938#turn_off_alerts

Comment: that will disable the alert, but that is not what I am looking for. Alert is ok (actually good) what I am trying to avoid is being blocked by gmail to send emails or Azure VM from moving around.

Comment: The warning are doing exactly what they are designed to do, so if you want to leave them on you would need to get a [static IP for your VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal)

Comment: I know, however I am passing the same user id and password. The gmail's problem is the IP's geo-location. And what I am seeing is when the Azure VM boots up everyday it gets a new IP, and it can be in EAST/CENTRAL/WEST and that geolocation causes gmail to panic into hack attack. There are no miss-attempts like wrong password.